# how to cache the objects for display tags in jsp JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl, displaytag

I am using the displaytag for the pagination purpose.

Now from the DB, I have a millions of records, to go one from the other page, its taking a quite longer time.

Is there a way we can cache the objects which needs to be shown, and so that traversing in between the pages can be faster.

Requirement : We are querying and displaying the number of files in the directory under Linux environment. each folders has thousands of files..

Answer (score 1):

How are your reading from DB? It would be good to see some more from your implementation.

As a general guideline:

1. If you read all your data into a list from the DB and only display a page, you will be wasting resources (processing and memory). This can kill your app. Try an approach that will just go for the page you're needing.
2. If you are using a framework like Hibernate, you can implement caching and paging without much trouble.
3. If you are using direct JDBC, you will have to limit registers in your query. Here the proper technique might depend on the Database Engine you're using. Please provide this information.
4. Be aware that your problem might be the amount of read information rather than a caching problem (just depends on the implementation).

As a sample, in Oracle, you would need to know the page and the pagesize. With both, you could limit the query with "where rownum < pagesize * page" (or something similar depending on how you index, and navigate to the first register you need with the absolute(int) method of Resultset. On other Engines it might be more efficient.

Now, if you're paginating with some framework, normally they support some implementation of a "DataProvider" so you can control how to fetch results for each page.